# Detecting when an attribute is removed

Tags: angular

I have a component on which there's an attribute who's value doesn't matter, just whether it exists or not. Up till now, I've just been getting it as an `Input`, and if it exists (checked in `onInit`), I set it to true.

However, to make the component a bit more flexible, I want to handle a situation like this:

```
<my-component [attr.testAttr]="someExpression()">
```

So when the expression changes and `testAttr` is existent or not, it will be detected.

I tried a setter on the attribute, which triggers when the attribute is set, but does not when the attribute is removed, letting me detect unset -> set, but not set -> unset.

I can't think of how to detect this change. An observable that watches attributes would be nice. I saw there is an `@Attribute` decorator, but it doesn't seem to take callbacks, and I don't see how it's useful.

Comment: A setter wouldn’t be called when the object assigned to it changes, only when a new object is assigned. Have you tried implementing OnChanges? If that doesn’t get triggered, you may need manual change detection.

Comment: I tried `OnChanges` originally, but don't think it worked; I'll test again. I have no idea how to do manual detection :/

Comment: I’m sure research can help you out with that!